# column does not have a default value laravel

Tags: mysql, insert, laravel-6

When Iam trying to insert a user filed I got an error,

`profile_image does not have a default value` , but Iam not insert any value to this column

**RegisterController.php**

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return Customer::create([
            'first_name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'customer_password' => hash('sha512', $data['password'])
        ]);
    }
```

**Model**

```
protected $fillable = ['first_name','email','customer_password'];
```

**Schema**

```
public function up()
    {
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE customers MODIFY profile_image varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL');
    }
```

why this happens ???

Thank you.

Comment: Could you add your Customer table schema?

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ updated my question with schema

Comment: The error you are getting is consistent with the `ALTER TABLE` statement which adds a default _not_ having already been run.  So, run the alter statement before adding your new model.

Comment: How did you generate your Customer model? is it based on `Customers` table?

Answer (score 0):

please pass blank string place of profile_image like this

```html
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return Customer::create([
            'first_name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'customer_password' => hash('sha512', $data['password']),
            'profile_image' => ""
        ]);
    }
```

OR

If you are change the table ,  create a migration like this

```html
Schema::table('table_name', function(Blueprint $table) {

    $table->string('profile_imae')->nullable()->change();

});
```

Comment: but why this happens ?

Comment: because we are not sending the any value of profile image by default database get null value , so that's way error comes

Comment: you simply add a blank string

Comment: but in model I define the fillable fileds

Comment: but in fillable fields profile_image is not present

Comment: because i don't want to insert any values to that filed. i need to insert only 'first_name','email','customer_password'